# join with 2 different sizes arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, join, clickhouse

How is it possible to modify query to pull out data from 2 arrays with different sizes from ClickHouse table?
At the moment I have following query which works properly:

```
   SELECT
   concat(toString(ApplicationID),': ',dictGetString('Application','Name',CAST(ApplicationID as 
   UInt64))) as site,
   concat(toString(SpotID),': ',dictGetString('Spot','Name',CAST(SpotID as UInt64))) as `Spot`,
   dictGetString('Domain', 'Value', DomainMap.ID) AS sourceDomain,
   toFloat64(sum(DomainMap.Impressions)) as cnt,
   SUM(DomainMap.Price/1000000000) as p,
   SUM(DomainMap.Revenue/1000000000) as r,
   p - r as res
   FROM distributed.publishers_map array Join DomainMap
   WHERE ActionDate = '2021-05-16' and ApplicationID in (4749)
   GROUP BY
   DomainMap.ID,
   ApplicationID,SpotID
   ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Then I need to add data from similar array which name is ExternalSpotMap. From this array I need to get as well

```
   SUM(ExternalSpotMap.Price/1000000000) as p,
   SUM(ExternalSpotMap.Revenue/1000000000) as r,
   p - r as res
```

And to add to the data from above mentioned existing query.
The problem is that these 2 arrays - DomainMap and ExternalSpotMap are of different sizes and I cannot make just following:

```
FROM distributed.publishers_map array Join DomainMap, ExternalSpotMap
```

Option 2. If I make following:

```
SELECT *
   from
   (
   Select *
   from
   (
   SELECT
   concat(toString(ApplicationID),': ',dictGetString('Application','Name',CAST(ApplicationID as 
   UInt64))) as site,
   concat(toString(SpotID),': ',dictGetString('Spot','Name',CAST(SpotID as UInt64))) as `Spot`,
   dictGetString('Domain', 'Value', DomainMap.ID) AS sourceDomain,
   toFloat64(sum(DomainMap.Impressions)) as cnt,
   SUM(DomainMap.Price/1000000000) as p,
   SUM(DomainMap.Revenue/1000000000) as r,
   p - r as res,
   SUM(ExternalSpotMap.Price/1000000000) as esmp,
   SUM(ExternalSpotMap.Revenue/1000000000) as esmr,
   esmp - esmr as res2
   FROM distributed.publishers_map
   WHERE ActionDate = '2021-05-16' and ApplicationID in (4749)
   GROUP BY DomainMap.ID, ApplicationID,SpotID
   ORDER BY cnt DESC
   )
   array join DomainMap
   )
   ARRAY JOIN ExternalSpotMap
```

Then I get an error:

```
SQL Error [43]: ClickHouse exception,  Code: 43, e.displayText() = 
DB::Exception: Illegal type Array(Int64) of argument for aggregate function 
sum
```

What could be the reason of issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            1,
            [1, 2, 3] AS a,
            ['a', 'b'] AS b
    )
    ARRAY JOIN a
)
ARRAY JOIN b


┌─1─┬─a─┬─b─┐
│ 1 │ 1 │ a │
│ 1 │ 1 │ b │
│ 1 │ 2 │ a │
│ 1 │ 2 │ b │
│ 1 │ 3 │ a │
│ 1 │ 3 │ b │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: Hello @Denny Crane. Thank You for Your attention. I added result under topic "Option 2" in my request above. Could You please look there ? Did I recreate query as You planned it?